# ListView: removing spaces between items, and limiting number of items in a listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-activity

I have a list, and I found that there is too much spacing seperating the list items. I would like to reduce it, but not sure how.

Below is the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#f2f2f2"
                >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iSchedule"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:padding="0dip"


        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/message_left" />

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="@color/off_white"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relSendMessage" />

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relSendMessage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:background="#ddd"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageBodyField"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:hint="@string/message_elipses"
            android:inputType="text|textNoSuggestions|none"
           android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ "

            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textColorLink="#adefda"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                android:layout_width="72dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_send" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/iSchedule"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:alpha="0.7"
        android:background="#C11B17"
        android:text="event"
        android:textColor="#f2f2f2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <com.parse.ParseImageView
        android:id="@+id/iProfilempic1"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/iSchedule"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_solid_light_holo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tMName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tMActivityName1"
        android:textColor="#292826"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:maxLength="40"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tMActivityName1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"

        android:layout_below="@+id/tMName1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iProfilempic1"
                android:maxLength="40"

        android:textColor="#292826"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:typeface="serif" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I would also like to limit the amount of items in the list 25. where no more than 25 items can be displayed in the list, and is wondering if i could achieve this within the layout, and not programmable (not using custom adapter).

Below is how the list is declare in the java code:

```
messagesList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMessages);
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(this);
        messagesList.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
```

Comment: What does your list item layout look like?

Answer (score 1):

You already have `dividerHeight=0dp`. That's as close as it's gonna get. The only other thing that might explain the extra spacing between items is padding in the actual item Views themselves. You might wanna reduce that padding.

As for your limit of 25, this is not possible in the way you specify. The only way to restrict this is to programmatically restrict the contents of your adapter. A very simple way to achieve this (using an [`ArrayAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)):

```
private void addItems(Collection<String> items) {
    for (String item : items) {
       if (mAdapter.getCount() < 25) {
           mAdapter.add(item);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have resolved the first case. For the second one, would it be possible to set the limit without using a custom adapter? If so, would you guide me in this journey. Thank you so much